# Use Hadoop Pig to load data from text file w/ each record on multiple lines?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have my data file in the following format:

```
U:    john
T:    2011-03-03 12:12:12
L:    san diego, CA

U:    john
T:    2011-03-03 12:12:12
L:    san diego, CA
```

What's the best way to read this file w/ Hadoop/pig/whatever for analysis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any way you can control the way the data is being written? Writing an process that moves this to tab separated would help you do this out of the box.

Otherwise, writing a custom record reader (in Pig or Java MapReduce) might be your only option. Neither is very hard.

Comment: Unfortunately, rewriting the data isn't an option.  I haven't had much luck figuring out how to write a custom record reader.  Can you help me w/ an example of how this works? Thanks!

Comment: You have to implement InputFormat: http://hadoop.apache.org/mapreduce/docs/r0.21.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/InputFormat.html

Comment: RecordReader: http://hadoop.apache.org/mapreduce/docs/r0.21.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/RecordReader.html

Comment: Sorry, I don't know of any specific tutorials or anything... best of luck.

Comment: This looks like it's going to be too much effort to accomplish. I better take a second look at rewriting the data :(  Thanks for the suggestion.. I should note: I'm currently doing the processing w/ my mapper function, but was hoping to switch to Pig, so the rewrite of the data allows me to use pig, but sort of kills the speed gains I'd get by switching to pig :p