# Is it possible to use Pig streaming (StreamToPig) in a way that handles multiple lines as a single input tuple?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

I'm streaming data in a pig script through an executable that returns an xml fragment for each line of input I stream to it. That xml fragment happens to span multiple lines and I have no control whatsoever over the output of the executable I stream to

In relation to [Use Hadoop Pig to load data from text file w/ each record on multiple lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6726407/use-hadoop-pig-to-load-data-from-text-file-w-each-record-on-multiple-lines), the answer was suggesting writing a custom record reader. The problem is, this works fine if you want to implement a LoadFunc that reads from a file, but to be able to use streaming, it has to implement StreamToPig. StreamToPig allows you to only read one line at a time as far as I understood

Does anyone know how to handle such a situation?

Answer (score 0):

If you are absolutely sure, then one option is to manage it internally to the streaming solution. That is to say, you build up the tuple yourself, and when you hit whatever your desired size is, you do the processing and return a value. In general, evalfuncs in pig have this issue.